# Incorrect syntax near 'order'. Running Total. SQL Server 2012

Tags: syntax, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

This code:

```
select 
    AccountCode.AccountCodeID,
    sum(AccountCode.AccountCodeID) Over (order by AccountCodeID) as RunningTotal
from 
    AccountCode
```

causes this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

on SQL Server 2012. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax seems fine - so it *should* work against SQL Server 2012.

There's two possibilities that it's still not valid:

- you're running SQL Server 2012 **Management Studio**, but against an older SQL Server **engine** version - you can check this by running:

  ```
  SELECT @@VERSION
  ```
- you're running with a database that has a lower **compatibility level** and thus doesn't support the SQL Server 2012 features, like the `OVER (ORDER BY...)` window function.

  Find out by running this against your database:

  ```
  SELECT name, compatibility_level 
  FROM sys.databases 
  WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
  ```

  The compatibility level should be **110** for SQL Server 2012 - if it's lower that that, you might want to change that.

**Update:** since you've determined that the compatibility level of this database is **80** (= SQL Server 2000), you need to change that to a more recent version. To upgrade your database to compatibility level **105** (SQL Server 2008 R2) which should support those window functions, use this command:

```
ALTER DATABASE (YourDatabaseName)
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 105;
```

and you're done. Now your query should work just fine.

Comment: Don't have a 2012 instance to hand, but confirmed this works fine on SQL 2014 (12.0.4213.0) if `AccountCodeID` is an `INT` column as I've assumed it is.  +1

Comment: I ran SELECT @@VERSION and got Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4033.0 (X64) 
 Jul  9 2014 16:04:25 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) but when I go to 'About' the logo is SQL Server 2012.  Second qry gives compatibility level 80

Comment: @DasalKalubowila: compatibility level **80** is SQL Server **2000** which **definitely** didn't support those window functions! Update your database's compatibility level to 100 for SQL Server 2008, and it should work.

Comment: The "About" box is the info about the **Management Studio** GUI tool - this has **nothing** to do with the actual underlying database **engine** ....

Comment: You guys are well helpful. I ran the script on an upgraded Test environment and it worked well. I'm not an admin and cannot run 'Alter' scripts. But is there any risk to the application if the db compatibility level is increased whilst keeping the the front end application as is?

Comment: @DasalKalubowila: changing the compatibility level of your database to a higher number basically only unlocks additional T-SQL features - it means that the SQL code executed against the database can make use of more T-SQL features than before. SQL Server typically is very very careful about *removing* previously existing features (that might no longer be available to your code). But it is a database-wide change, so I'd definitely do it in a TEST environment first and test my app(s) thoroughly!